# To explode the string based on the special characters in Php

Tags: php, special-characters, explode

I have a string:

```
xyz.com?username="test"&pwd="test"@score="score"#key="1234"
```

output format:

```
array (
    [0] => username="test"
    [1] => pwd="test"
    [2] => score="score"
    [3] => key="1234"
)
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: preg_split ( "/\?|&|@|#/", $string )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with a [character class](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) with all delimiters in it. At the end just use [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) to remove the first element.

```
<?php

    $str = 'xyz.com?username="test"&pwd="test"@score="score"#key="1234"';

    $arr = preg_split("/[?&@#]/", $str);
    array_shift($arr);

    print_r($arr);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => username="test"
    [1] => pwd="test"
    [2] => score="score"
    [3] => key="1234"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_split` function with regex pattern including all those delimimting special characters. Then remove the first value of the array and reset keys:

```
$s = 'xyz.com?username="test"&pwd="test"@score="score"#key="1234"';
$a = preg_split('/[?&@#]/',$s);
unset($a[0]);
$a = array_values($a);

print_r($a);
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
[0] => username="test" 
[1] => pwd="test" 
[2] => score="score" 
[3] => key="1234" 
)
```